# CSS3 Keyframes Do Not Override default background color in FF and IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, css, css-transitions, css-animations

In chrome, this works as intended:

"-webkit-animation: fadeBox 1s ease-in-out" overides "background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9)" in #lightbox{}.

But in mozilla and ie10 it seems that  "background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9)" in #lightbox overides the animation: fadeBox 4s ease-in-out; and I don't get the fade effect.

I have to have "background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9)" in #lightbox so when the keyframes are done the background color remains white.

Not sure what to do about this for firefox and IE10.

```
#lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9); <-----DEFAULT COLOR AFTER ANIMATION IS DONE
    z-index: 150;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-animation: fadeBox 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: fadeBox 4s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeBox 4s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeBox {
    0% { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.0) }
    100% { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9) }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeBox {
    0% { background-color: red }
    100% { background-color: red }
}

@keyframes fadeBox {
    0% { background-color: rgba(255,255,255.0) }
    100% { background-color: rgba(255,255,255.9) }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `@-ms-keyframes fadeBox` and why is the background-color red in the firefox keyframes?

Comment: I did red just to see if the moz-keyframe would take effect and it wouldn't. ie10 doens't use vender prefixes as far as I know.

Comment: @Philip Jens Bramsted: d hee is correct - `@-ms-keyframes` does not exist, IE10 uses unprefixed keyframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your keyframe CSS is not valid CSS.  In particular, in your `@keyframes`, which both IE and Mozilla are using, your `rgba()` has only three arguments, which is not valid for `rgba()`.

Note that the web console in Firefox tells you about your errors:

```
[11:11:50.588] Expected an integer but found '255'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. @ file:///tmp/test.html:27
[11:11:50.588] Expected an integer but found '255.9'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. @ file:///tmp/test.html:28
```